# Using temporary variables while calling function in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Often, I have seen functions being called like

```
$content = getContent($isAdmin = false)
```

Whereas the function declaration is like

```
function getContent($isAdmin = true){
....}
```

Why would anyone add a overload of creating a variable and using it only once in a function call !!

I understand that this makes the function call clear, but shouldn't we use PHPDoc blocks instead?

Comment: That variable assignment by the way is pretty cheap. You have the memory hassle anyway, even if there would not be a variable. PHP is very good with such things. Do not fear variables, even if you only use them once, use them. They will improve your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the feeling that you are deeply shocked by so much "waste".

Keep cool, using variables is nothing bad, you should use them often. They normally make your code more descriptive and even faster.

The more descriptive part is the case here, if you look at that line, you see which parameter that is because now it has a name.

> but shouldn't we use PHPDoc blocks instead?

Well, actually this is unrelated to (docblock) comments. Even in the function definition, there is no comment for *that* parameter:

```
function getContent($isAdmin = true) {
```

It's just the definition of the parameter by it's name. Also the docblock parameter would be only when you define the function:

```
...
 * @param $isAdmin bool (optional) true or false, true by default
...
function getContent($isAdmin = true) {
```

However that is not where the function is called:

```
$content = getContent($isAdmin = false)
```

So if you look at that line (and before pressing any hotkey or mouse button), you already read that. Nothing needed, only the code. Works even in notepad or an non-configured gedit.

```
$nonAdmin = false;
$content = getContent($nonAdmin);
```

And btw, if your code *needs* comments, this is normally a sign that it is too complicated. Also the name of a parameter is much more important than it's docblock. A good name normally means that you do not need to have a docblock tag for it (that means: less code to maintain), because the name speaks for itself.

Also modern IDEs know the type of the parameter by static analysis and therefore you do not need the docblock tag either. So no, you do not just should always use PHPDocblocks.

Comment: +1 Strong argument i wonder when Keyword arguments would be supported in PHP

Comment: +1 for "So no, you do not just should always use PHPDocblocks.", this just made me wonder as most modern IDE's show the function parameter name along with its data type (if provided a default value)

Answer (score 3):

Writing like:

```
$content = getContent($isAdmin = false)
```

lets `$isAdmin` be defined even outside function scope, i.e. if you issue a `var_dump($isAdmin)`, you get `bool(false)`.

This way you save a var assignment:

```
$isAdmin = false;
$content = getContent($isAdmin);
...
someStuff($isAdmin);
```